# Asciidoctor::HTML5::DocumentTemplate replacement

Tags: ruby, html, gradle, asciidoctor

I have no experience with Asciidoctor, Ruby or gradle. I've been put in charge of a project developed by someone else which uses all 3 of this. In the code is  the function `Asciidoctor::HTML5::DocumentTemplate` which throws an error

We recently upgraded to Asciidoctor 1.5.0 and when trying to compile this project it throws the following error messages:

```
16:25:53.429 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (NameError) uninitialized constant Asciidoctor::HTML5
16:25:53.429 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.jruby.RubyModule.const_missing(org/jruby/RubyModule.java:2689)
16:25:53.430 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] at RUBY.__singleton__(/tmp/document.html.erb:108)
```

Line 108 is : `<%= ::Asciidoctor::HTML5::DocumentTemplate.outline(self, (attr :toclevels, 2).to_i) %>`

From what I can see, it populates the table of content from a file with titles with a ## tag in front of them.

What do I do from here?

Comment: Lots has changed in Asciidoctor 1.5.0, the templates are no longer there, instead they're converters and the API has changed quite a bit. Could you please post up the full document.html.erb? Or if you are up for it, post the diff between it and the version you were on before (I assume 0.1.4). I also recommend you post on http://discuss.asciidoctor.org/ as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your *document.html.erb* is probably based on [asciidoctor-v0.1.4/erb/html5/document.html.erb](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-backends/blob/asciidoctor-v0.1.4/erb/html5/document.html.erb). That one works for asciidoctor 0.1.4, but not for 1.5. A version that works with 1.5 can be found here: [master/erb/html5/document.html.erb](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-backends/blob/master/erb/html5/document.html.erb).

Between these two versions, the line

```
<%= ::Asciidoctor::HTML5::DocumentTemplate.outline(self, (attr :toclevels, 2).to_i) %>
```

is replaced with

```
<%= converter.convert self, 'outline' %>
```

Changing that line in my copy of *document.html.erb* resolved the error for me.

Comment: Your answer is probably better than mine for this instance :)

Answer (score 0):

Your line 108 should be changed to say:

```
<%= ::Asciidoctor::Converter::Html5Converter.outline(self) =%>
```

However, as I said in the comments, I'd need to see more to see if there are other things that need to be changed.